# Oracle sql query with "non-attribute" function. Ora-00935

Tags: sql, oracle

I have simple database:

```
Paintings {
    PAINTING_ID
    PAINTING_NAME
    AUTHOR
    MUSEUM
}
Museums {
    MUSEUM_ID
    MUSEUM_NAME
}

Authors {
    AUTHOR_ID
    AUTHOR_NAME
}
```

`AUTHOR` and `MUSEUM` in paintings are foreign keys.

I have the task:

- Display name for museum, that has the largest number of paintings of author id 6.

I tried some things:

```
SELECT MUSEUM.MUSEUM_NAME
FROM PAINTINGS
INNER JOIN AUTHORS
ON AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID = PAINTINGS.AUTHOR
INNER JOIN MUSEUMS
ON MUSEUMS.MUSEUM_ID = PAINTINGS.MUSEUM
--WHERE AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID = 6
GROUP BY MUSEUM_ID
HAVING MAX(COUNT(AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID = 6)) // Ora-00935
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT()
FROM PAINTINGS
WHERE PAINTINGS.AUTHOR = 6
```

It looks like I must use aggregate function or sub-query function instead attribute, that actually impossible.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can find the ID of the museum(s) with largest number of paintings using:

```sql
SELECT museum_id
FROM   paintings
GROUP BY museum_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

to restrict it to a single author you can add a `WHERE` filter:

```sql
SELECT museum_id
FROM   paintings
WHERE  author = 6
GROUP BY museum_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

If you want the name of the museum then you can `JOIN` to the museum table (and either include `museum_name` in the `GROUP BY` clause or, because there is a correspondence from `museum_id` to `museum_name`, you can use an aggregation function to find the name):

```sql
SELECT MAX(museum_name) AS museum_name
FROM   paintings p
       INNER JOIN museums m
       ON (p.museum_id = m.museum_id)
WHERE  p.author = 6
GROUP BY p.museum_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

Comment: Great, it works, thanks for answering! And for editing post (sorry).